# undefined variable error while parsing data into DOMPDF

Tags: php, html, dompdf

**This is my code**

```
$values = $Viewer->getPrintData($_GET['id']);

                    if($values->num_rows > 0)
                        {
                            while($row = $values->fetch_assoc())
                                {
                                    switch($row['birth_type_id'])
                                            {
                                                    case 1: $hospital_id = $row['hospital_id'];
                                                            $home_detail = "None";
                                                            $other_detail = "None";
                                                            $birth_formatted_type = "Birth at : ".$Viewer->getHospitalName($row['hospital_id']);
                                                            break;

                                                    case 2: $hospital_id = "None";
                                                            $home_detail = $row['home_detail'];
                                                            $other_detail = "None";
                                                            $birth_formatted_type = "|| Birth at Home || <br />Home Details Are : ".$row['home_detail'];
                                                            break;

                                                    case 3: $hospital_id = "None";
                                                            $home_detail = "None";
                                                            $other_detail = $row['other_detail'];
                                                            $birth_formatted_type = "|| Birth at Other Location || <br />Details Are : ".$row['other_detail'];
                                                            break;

                                                    default:
                                                            $hospital_id = "None";
                                                            $home_detail = "None";
                                                            $other_detail = "None";
                                                            break;
                                            }

                                    $data .= "
                                                <br />
                                                <center>
                                                    <h2>
                                                        Birth Certificate Details
                                                    </h2>
                                                </center>
                                                <div style='width: 100%;'>
                                                    <table>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style='width: 350px;'>
                                                                <u>
                                                                    <h3>Baby Related Details</h3>
                                                                </u>
                                                                Registration Number: ".$row['registration_number']."<br />
                                                                Birth Date: ".$row['birth_date']."<br />
                                                                Birth Time: ".$row['birth_time']."<br /><br />
                                                                Gender: ".$Viewer->getGender($row['gender_id'])."<br />
                                                                Baby's Full Name: ".$row['baby_name']."<br />
                                                                Father's Full Name: ".$row['fathers_name']."<br />
                                                                Father's Aadhar ID: ".$row['fathers_uid']."<br />
                                                                Mother's Full Name: ".$row['mothers_name']."<br />
                                                                Mother's Aadhar ID: ".$row['mothers_uid']."<br />
                                                                While Baby's Birth Parents Address: ".$row['while_baby_birth_parents_address']."<br />
                                                                Parent's Permanent Address: ".$row['parents_permanent_address']."<br />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style='width: 350px;'>
                                                                <u>
                                                                    <h3>Parents Details</h3>
                                                                </u>
                                                                {$birth_formatted_type}<br />
                                                                Religion: ".$row['religion']."<br /><br />
                                                                Taluka: ".$Viewer->getTalukaDetail($row['taluka_id'])."<br />
                                                                City: ".$Viewer->getCityDetail($row['city_id'])."<br />
                                                                Pincode: ".$Viewer->getPincodeDetail($row['pincode_id'])."
                                                                <br /><br />
                                                                Father's Education Level: ".$Viewer->getEducationLevel($row['id_of_fathers_education_level'])."<br />
                                                                Mother's Education Level: ".$Viewer->getEducationLevel($row['id_of_mothers_education_level'])."}<br />
                                                                Father's Occupation: ".$Viewer->getOccupationDetail($row['id_of_fathers_occupation'])."<br />
                                                                Mother's Occupation: ".$Viewer->getOccupationDetail($row['id_of_mothers_occupation'])."

                                                                <u>
                                                                    <h3><br />Other Details</h3>
                                                                </u>    
                                                                Mother's Marriage Age: ".$row['mothers_marriage_age']."<br />
                                                                While Baby's Birth Mother's Age: ".$row['while_birth_mothers_age']."<br />
                                                                Alive Deliveries Upto Now: ".$row['total_alive_deliveries_uptill_date']."<br /><br />
                                                                Birth Place / Person: ".$Viewer->getBirthPlaceOrPerson($row['id_of_birth_place_person'])."<br />
                                                                Mother's Delivery Type: ".$Viewer->getDeliveryType($row['id_of_delivery_type'])."<br />
                                                                Child's Weight: ".$row['child_weight_while_birth']."<br />
                                                                Pregnancy Duration: ".$row['pregnancy_duration']."
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                             ";
                                }

                            $html_data = "
                                            <html>
                                                <head>
                                                    <style>
                                                        *
                                                            {
                                                                font-family: 'oswald';
                                                            }
                                                        @page
                                                            {
                                                                margin: 10px;
                                                            }
                                                        body, table
                                                            {
                                                                margin: 10px;
                                                                page-break-after: always;
                                                            }
                                                    </style>
                                                </head>
                                                <body>
                                                ".$data."
                                                </body>
                                            </html>
                                         ";    

                            echo $html_data;

                            // require "../dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php";
                            // $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
                            // $dompdf->load_html($html_data);
                            // $dompdf->render();
                            // $dompdf->stream("PD_.pdf");    
                        }
```

i am getting an error like

> Notice: Undefined variable: data in xyz folder location on line 98
>   (May vary)

i don't know why the error i occurring but, it's showing the output when the i am doing echo in browser with the error specified. It is giving the problem while generating the pdf. When the pdf is generated it shows the pdf id damaged format.

Comment: define as `$data=""` at top level

Comment: Ohk that worked perfectly i guess that had to be defined first :)

Comment: yes.. u r right..